# How to switch to a different tab and reset all tabs in TabNavigator in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

This has been asked in many different forms and I searched all week but could not figure out how to navigate from `Connect` back to `Devices` in the below setup.

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
    Devices: DevicesScreen,
    Details: DetailsScreen, // go here
})

const NewDeviceStack = createStackNavigator({
    Start: StartScreen,
    Connect: ConnectScreen, // start here
})

const BottomTabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
    Home: { screen: HomeStack },
    Settings: { screen: NewDeviceStack },
}

export default createAppContainer(BottomTabs);
```

From the `Connect` screen this code attempts to reset current stack and go back to `Devices`

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        key: null,
        actions: [
            NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'Devices'})
            ],
        })
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

This fails with:

```
Error: There is no route defined for key Devices.
Must be one of: 'Start','Connect'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `navigation` prop, on click of a button navigate to devices screen

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Devices')
```

or just create a function to handle navigation

```
goToScreen = (routeName, params = {}) => {

  const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName: routeName,

    params: params, // parameter

    action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: routeName }), // screen you want to navigate to
  });

  this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);

};
```

Comment: thanks i will try this. how to force reload/re-render the Devices screen upon navigation?

Comment: it should refresh, when you land there.

Comment: ok tried it. the screen switches from `Connect` to `Devices` but `componentDidMount` or `render` are not called. any listeners to add?

Comment: `componentDidMount` does get called  see https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/delete-me

Comment: *ok tried it. the screen switches from Connect to Devices* this answers your question, and should be marked as an answer. If something doesn't work create a new question for that, instead of adding new question to the existing one.

Comment: @JuniusL. it works thanks. there was a `async` call to save data in my case but `navigate` would complete first so it appeared like reset was not happening. @TenTen - question clearly says 'switch and reset' so no new question was added.